# Move page number position for a specific page

Tags: page-numbering, overleaf, geometry, layout

I am using overleaf and the official Elsevier template to write a paper (for the first time in latex). In my document there is one large figure with long caption, I have to put them in a new page with custom margins to properly accommodate them:

```
\usepackage{geometry}

\newgeometry{a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=22mm,
 top=10mm,}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{figures/figure2.png}
    \caption{A long caption}
    \label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}
\restoregeometry
```

But there is one problem for this page that the page number is too close to the bottom (see picture below). Is there a way to adjust the position of the page number for this specific page, while keeping the other pages unchanged?
[image]

Comment: Let the editors worry about it.  You are in charge of content, while they are in charage of aesthetics.

Comment: Please apply this checklist next time on your code snippet to present a MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790